# Pattern with optional argument in replacement rule

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to define a replacement rule with optional argument `color_RGBColor` which should be replaced with `Sequence[]` when it is absent in the original expression:

```
style[line_Line, ___, 
  color_RGBColor: Unevaluated@Sequence[], ___] :> {color, line}
```

When `RGBColor` is present in the original expression, the rule works:

```
style[Line[], RGBColor[{}]] /. 
 style[line_Line, ___, 
   color_RGBColor: Unevaluated@Sequence[], ___] :> {color, line}

=> {RGBColor[{}], Line[]}
```

But when it is absent, it does not:

```
style[Line[], Thickness[0.01]] /. 
 Style[line_Line, ___, 
   color_RGBColor: Unevaluated@Sequence[], ___] :> {color, line}

=> style[Line[], Thickness[0.01]]
```

My questions are:

1) Why it does not work?

2) Is it possible to construct a single pattern which will work as desired?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your pattern does not work because of the way the pattern-matching works for the default (optional) arguments, and also because you restricted the head to be `RGBColor`. The problem is that the default argument value must match the pattern, while `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]` certainly does not match `_RGBColor`.

You have several ways out. A first attempt is to weaken your type-checking:

```
In[10]:= style[Line[],Thickness[0.01]]/.
style[line_Line,___,color_: Unevaluated@Sequence[],___]:>{color,line}

Out[10]= {Thickness[0.01],Line[]}
```

But this does not work since the matching is incorrect - the typing is indeed too weak. The hacky way to make it work is this:

```
In[14]:= style[Line[], RGBColor[{}]] /. 
 style[line_Line, ___, color : (_RGBColor | _Unevaluated) : 
    Unevaluated@Sequence[], ___] :> {Evaluate@color, line}


Out[14]= {RGBColor[{}], Line[]}

In[15]:= style[Line[], Thickness[0.01]] /. 
  style[line_Line, ___, color : (_RGBColor | _Unevaluated) : 
     Unevaluated@Sequence[], ___] :> {Evaluate@color, line}

Out[15]= {Line[]}
```

The recommended way to do it is this:

```
In[18]:= style[Line[], Thickness[0.01]] /. 
style[line_Line, ___, color : (_RGBColor | Automatic) : Automatic, ___] :> 
  If[color === Automatic, {line}, {color, line}]


Out[18]= {Line[]}

In[17]:= style[Line[], RGBColor[{}]] /. 
 style[line_Line, ___, color : (_RGBColor | Automatic) : Automatic, ___] :> 
   If[color === Automatic, {line}, {color, line}]


Out[17]= {RGBColor[{}], Line[]}
```

This feature of the pattern-matcher is not very widely known, so I will stress it again: the default value for the (optional) pattern `x:ptrn:default` must match `ptrn`. For another example of such behavior, see [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/2c8d61af757c33c2/) Mathgroup discussion.

Comment: Thank you! Is this feature completely undocumented?

Comment: I have not seen it documented, but may be I was just not paying enough attention and it is written somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: Meanwhile, it is allowed to have a default value which does not match the pattern.

Comment: @user7427029 Indeed. But this wasn't always the case

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this works for you:

```
style[Line[a], RGBColor[{}]] /. 
 style[line_Line, ___, Longest[color___RGBColor], ___] :> {color,line}
(*
{RGBColor[{}], Line[a]}
*)

style[Line[]] /. 
 style[line_Line, ___, Longest[color___RGBColor], ___] :> {color, line}
(*
{Line[]}
*)
```

I guess your replacement rule does not work just because there is no element with a Head `RGBColor`, so there is no match.

Comment: In this way `Longest` and even `Optional` are not needed - replacement of `Blank` with `BlankNullSequence` does the trick: `style[Line[]] /. style[line_Line, ___, color___RGBColor, ___] :> {color, line}`. But why it does not work with `Blank`?

Comment: @Alexey I was editing when you posted your comment :). I did the same